# Вопрос про чат на Pywebio на Python + Ngrok

Tags: python

На ютубе рассказывается, [как создать чат на питоне](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HnSPz2bK_bs&t=326s) с использованием библиотеки pywebio.
Но не рассказывается, как его в глобалку выложить. Увидел, что создатель видео использует ngrok. Вопрос в том, как сделать так, чтобы у каждого был доступ к этой странице так же используя ngrok?
PS знаю про tornado, flask, django..интересно, как сделать это именно на ngrok'e

```
import asyncio
from pywebio import start_server
from pywebio.input import *
from pywebio.output import *
from pywebio.session import defer_call, info as session_info, run_async, run_js
chat_msgs = []
online_users = set()
MAX_MESSAGES_COUNT = 100
async def main():
    global chat_msgs
    put_markdown("Добро пожаловать в онлайн чат!")
    msg_box = output()
    put_scrollable(msg_box, height=300, keep_bottom=True)
    nickname = await input("Войти в чат", required=True, placeholder="Ваше имя", validate=lambda n: "Такой ник уже используется!" if n in online_users or n == '' else None)
    online_users.add(nickname)
    chat_msgs.append(('', f'`{nickname}` присоединился к чату!'))
    msg_box.append(put_markdown(f' `{nickname}` присоединился к чату'))
    refresh_task = run_async(refresh_msg(nickname, msg_box))
    while True:
        data = await input_group(" Новое сообщение", [input(placeholder="Текст сообщения ...", name="msg"),actions(name="cmd", buttons=["Отправить", {'label': "Выйти из чата", 'type': 'cancel'}])], validate=lambda m: ('msg', "Введите текст сообщения!") if m["cmd"] == "Отправить" and not m['msg'] else None)
        if data is None: break
        msg_box.append(put_markdown(f"`{nickname}`: {data['msg']}"))
        chat_msgs.append((nickname, data['msg']))
    refresh_task.close()
    online_users.remove(nickname)
    toast("Вы вышли из чата!")
    msg_box.append(put_markdown(f' Пользователь `{nickname}` покинул чат!'))
    chat_msgs.append(('', f'Пользователь `{nickname}` покинул чат!'))
    put_buttons(['Перезайти'], onclick=lambda btn: run_js('window.location.reload()'))
async def refresh_msg(nickname, msg_box):
    global chat_msgs
    last_idx = len(chat_msgs)
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        for m in chat_msgs[last_idx:]: 
            if m[0] != nickname: msg_box.append(put_markdown(f"`{m[0]}`: {m[1]}"))
        if len(chat_msgs) > MAX_MESSAGES_COUNT: chat_msgs = chat_msgs[len(chat_msgs) // 2:]
        last_idx = len(chat_msgs)
if __name__ == "__main__": start_server(main, debug=True, port=8080, cdn=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Скачиваете ngrok, и после запуска вашего приложения на python в окне ngrok вводите команду `ngrok http 5000` (где 5000 - это порт, на котором вы запускаете сервер в пайтоне).

В ответ получите тоннель с веб адресом, который будет активен несколько часов.